# Did this woman die of a heart attack?

Tags: cardiology

The video below circulated in Singapore (and I think Malaysia too) on Whatsapp and Facebook with the accompanying message. (Though my guess is that it was taken in China.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV5y9Xr71gQ

> Accompanying message
>
> This lady collapsed suddenly due to heart attack while delivering her
>   speech as incoming president of a social club. She was immediately
>   sent to hospital but unfortunately was pronounced dead on arrival. So
>   sad. Pay attention at the 1:13 mark when she was rubbing her hands
>   (due to lack of blood circulation). Doctor said that when you
>   experienced coldness in extremities such as hands and shortness of
>   breath, you have only 4 to 5 seconds before onset of heart attack. You
>   have to quickly sit down and start taking very deep breaths to try
>   saving yourself while getting medical help. Pls take care everybody.

My question is: Did this woman really die of a heart attack and was pronounced DOA at the hospital, shortly after this video was taken (as claimed by the accompanying message?

Comment: I am far more interested in whether the "You have to quickly sit down and start taking very deep breaths to try saving yourself" claim is accurate medically.

Comment: Before the onset of a heart attack??  Circulatory issues are one of the symptoms of a heart attack!

Comment: @user5341 Agreed. Maybe start a new question?

Comment: @kenny - any objections?